# INaturalist17 JSON annotation format to Darket format for detection

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, yolov5, darknet, yolov8

INaturalist17 JSON annotation format to Darket format for detection

I have been recently trying to convert the JSON annotation files of the INaturalist17 dataset to Darknet format for doing object detection. Each image should have its own annotation file in text file as shown in the attached image.
[inat2darknet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7jTf.png)